# Round user input to nearest 1/4” on input from laser measurer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a laser measurer that automatically enters the measurement into a number cell.  The only problem is it’s too accurate, I need it to round to the nearest 1/4”. I don’t want to have to stop and fix each number that gets entered. I have tried to change the way the laser measurer sends data to Excel, but it can only send decimal inches and only exactly what it measurers.
I would prefer not to have to use 2 cells one to get the number and another to round it. I’ve searched Google with no results, any help would be greatly appreciated!
(Windows 11, Excel)
Thanks

Comment: [MROUND function - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mround-function-c299c3b0-15a5-426d-aa4b-d2d5b3baf427)

Comment: What have you tried?  What are some example inputs?  What are your expected outputs?  What are your actual outputs? [Edit] your question to include the required information to answer your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: See if there is something in your laser measurer that can output to the 1/4 inch. You could change excel number format to fractions as quarters but that would only be visual (the orginal precision would be what is actually in the cell).

Comment: If you need to actually `ROUND` the value in place, without a helper column, you will need to write a VBA macro to either intercept the input stream from the laser ruler, or Round the numbers in place. If it is just a display issue, you can just change the number format. Changing the number format to `# ?/4`, however, will display `1.507` as `1 2/4` and not as `1 1/2`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom formatting to show your results as fractions.
Additionally you can check in Excel options `Set precision as displayed`.
Values will then be rounded permanently.
[image: quarters]